# Tic-Tac-Toe in Java with GUI

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

I've wrote a little program to play Tic-Tac-Toe:

```java
public class Control {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Gui gui = new Gui();

    }
}
```

The following classed is used for applying the rules of tic-tac-toe:

```java
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe {
    public static int count = 0;
    public static String[][] board = new String[3][3];
    public boolean test = true;

    public void buttonClicked(JButton button) {
        if(test) {
            if(button.getText().equals("")) {
                count++;
                if(count % 2 == 1) {
                    button.setText("X");
                }
                if(count % 2 == 0) {
                    button.setText("O");
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public void gameRules(JButton button) {
        if(test) {

            //"X" or "O"?
            String string = button.getText();

            //Gives coordinates of the button
            int x = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(0));
            int y = Character.getNumericValue(button.getName().charAt(1));
            board[x][y] = string;

            if(board[0][0] != null && board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][2])) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won.");
                test = false;
            }

            else if(board[0][2] != null && board[0][2].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][0])) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,string + " won.");
                test = false;
            }
            else if(count == 9) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "draw.");
                test = false;
            }
            else {
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    if (board[i][0] != null && board[i][0].equals(board[i][1]) && board[i][0].equals(board[i][2])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string + " won.");
                        test = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (board[0][i] != null && board[0][i].equals(board[1][i]) && board[0][i].equals(board[2][i])) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, string + " won.");
                        test = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally the class for the GUI:

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class Gui {
    public Gui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        TicTacToe ticTacToe = new TicTacToe();
        panel.setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout(3, 3));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                final JButton button = new JButton();
                String string = i +  "" + j;
                button.setText("");
                button.setName(string);
                button.addActionListener(
                        new ActionListener() {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                ticTacToe.buttonClicked(button);
                                ticTacToe.gameRules(button);
                            }
                        });
                button.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 40));
                button.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
                panel.add(button);
            }

        }

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(400,400);
        frame.setVisible(true);




    }
}
```

I would appreciate any suggestions to improve the code.

Comment: What's the point of the `test` variable

Comment: When on player won, it is set to false, and so noone will be able to add another "X" or "O" to the grid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Event Dispatching Thread

Since Swing is not thread safe, all Swing UI component creation and modification should be done on the Event Dispatching Thread (EDT).  It isn’t a problem with this program, but you could run into it if you also created (say) a `javax.swing.Timer` in your initiation.

It is an easy change to create the GUI on the EDT.  Instead of `Gui gui = new Gui();` use:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(Gui::new);
```

### But I Won???

Play a game, with these moves:

```
 O | X | O
---+---+---
 X |   | X
---+---+---
 O | X | O
```

And then put the final X in the center.  You win in two directions at once, but because `count == 9`, the game is a draw?

### Separate GUI / Logic

It looks like you tried to separate the GUI from the game logic, but:

- `TicTacToe` still accesses/manipulates `JButton` objects
- `TicTacToe` shows `JOptionPane` dialogs

So, it is not separate from the Swing GUI; you could not reuse it in an SWT or JavaFX application.

The `TicTacToe` class should have functions something like:

- `bool isValidMove(int x, int y)`
- `void makeMove(int x, int y)`
- `bool isGameOver()`
- `Player getWinner()`

and the GUI should convert buttons into x, y locations, display messages, etc

### `static`

Can you play a second game?  No.  There is no way to reset `count` for a new game.  It would continue to count above 9 with additional moves!

Can you play two games at once?  No!  There is only one `board` object.  Two simultaneous games would corrupt each other’s `board` and `count` variables!

Why are these variables `static`?  It prevents multiple `TicTacToe` objects from being created.  If you removed `static` from the variables, you could start a new game by creating a new `TicTacToe` object (and resetting the GUI).

**Advanced:** Also, you could allow the computer to experiment with different moves, and look several moves in the future, ... but only if you could create these extra `TicTacToe` boards which aren’t the ones being displayed in the UI.

### Simplify Logic

```
            if(count % 2 == 1) {
                button.setText("X");
            }
            if(count % 2 == 0) {
                button.setText("O");
            }
```

If `count % 2` is not `1`, it must be `0`.  Use an `else` clause:

```
            if(count % 2 == 1) {
                button.setText("X");
            } else {
                button.setText("O");
            }
```

---

This test is very verbose:

```
        if(board[0][0] != null && board[0][0].equals(board[1][1]) && board[1][1].equals(board[2][2])) {
```

Who can win on any turn?  The player that just made a move, of course.  And their symbol is stored in `string` (a terrible variable name, by the way).

So if the above test was to pass, all the symbols would equal `string`, so you could write it a little more concisely as:

```
        if(string.equals(board[0][0]) && string.equals(board[1][1]) && string.equals(board[2][2]) {
```

If you defined constants (or better, used `enum` if you are familiar with them):

```
    public final static String PLAYER_X = "X";
    public final static String PLAYER_O = "O";
```

and explicitly set the contents of `board[][]` to either one of those objects, then you could safely test for object **identity**, instead of **equality**:

```
        if(board[0][0] == player && board[1][1] == player && board[2][2] == player) {
```